# Populate table with 2D array jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

Description:

I've the random walker algorithm who returns a 2D array full of 0 and 1. With this algorithm, I can generate a random dungeon map, now I'm stuck in this problem: How can I fill an html table with this 0 and 1 ?

```
map = [[1,1,1,1,0],
       [1,0,0,0,0],
       [1,0,1,1,1],
       [1,0,0,0,1],
       [1,1,1,0,1]]
```

Do I have to generate the table dynamically ?

Objectives:

- Loop 2D array
- Fill (or better generate?) a table based on this 2D array

```
  function createArray(num, dimensions) {
    var array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < dimensions; i++) {
      array.push([]);
      for (var j = 0; j < dimensions; j++) {
        array[i].push(num);
      }
    }
    return array;
  }


  //lets create a randomly generated map for our dungeon crawler
function  createMap() {
    let dimensions = 32, // width and height of the map
      maxTunnels = 28, // max number of tunnels possible
      maxLength = 28, // max length each tunnel can have
      map = createArray(1, dimensions), // create a 2d array full of 1's
      currentRow = Math.floor(Math.random() * dimensions), // our current row - start at a random spot
      currentColumn = Math.floor(Math.random() * dimensions), // our current column - start at a random spot
      directions = [[-1, 0], [1, 0], [0, -1], [0, 1]], // array to get a random direction from (left,right,up,down)
      lastDirection = [], // save the last direction we went
      randomDirection; // next turn/direction - holds a value from directions

    // lets create some tunnels - while maxTunnels, dimentions, and maxLength  is greater than 0.
    while (maxTunnels && dimensions && maxLength) {

      // lets get a random direction - until it is a perpendicular to our lastDirection
      // if the last direction = left or right,
      // then our new direction has to be up or down,
      // and vice versa
      do {
         randomDirection = directions[Math.floor(Math.random() * directions.length)];
      } while ((randomDirection[0] === -lastDirection[0] && randomDirection[1] === -lastDirection[1]) || (randomDirection[0] === lastDirection[0] && randomDirection[1] === lastDirection[1]));

      var randomLength = Math.ceil(Math.random() * maxLength), //length the next tunnel will be (max of maxLength)
        tunnelLength = 0; //current length of tunnel being created

        // lets loop until our tunnel is long enough or until we hit an edge
      while (tunnelLength < randomLength) {

        //break the loop if it is going out of the map
        if (((currentRow === 0) && (randomDirection[0] === -1)) ||
            ((currentColumn === 0) && (randomDirection[1] === -1)) ||
            ((currentRow === dimensions - 1) && (randomDirection[0] === 1)) ||
            ((currentColumn === dimensions - 1) && (randomDirection[1] === 1))) {
          break;
        } else {
          map[currentRow][currentColumn] = 0; //set the value of the index in map to 0 (a tunnel, making it one longer)
          currentRow += randomDirection[0]; //add the value from randomDirection to row and col (-1, 0, or 1) to update our location
          currentColumn += randomDirection[1];
          tunnelLength++; //the tunnel is now one longer, so lets increment that variable
        }
      }

      if (tunnelLength) { // update our variables unless our last loop broke before we made any part of a tunnel
        lastDirection = randomDirection; //set lastDirection, so we can remember what way we went
        maxTunnels--; // we created a whole tunnel so lets decrement how many we have left to create
      }
    }
    return map; // all our tunnels have been created and our map is complete, so lets return it to our render()
  };
```

I can use only `jQuery` or `JavaScript`.

If there are better solutions instead of the table I will hear with all my pleasure.

Comment: *Do i have to generate the table dynamically ?*  Yes.  Unless your 2d array is always going to be a fixed size, in which case you could define the table statically and then fill in the cells with the generated data.

Comment: The table can has a static dimension, it's not necessary ( right now ) to have random dimension. I set in the algorithm the dimension of 32. 
Really thank you for this comment, it's my first question in stack overflow :)

Comment: Nothing complicated...loop to create rows...inner loop to add cells to each row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to your comments i found this solution 5 days ago, but i forget to update the post. So here we are :)

```
function mapGenerate(){
    var map=createMap();


        //loop the 2d array map and change the number with the appropriate img    
        for(var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
            var innerArrayLength = map[i].length;
            for(var j = 0; j<innerArrayLength; j++){
                //loop the nested arrays so i can change the 1 and the 0 with the appropriate img
                if(map[i][j] === 0){
                    map[i][j]="<img class=\"walkble\" src=\"mapTiles/floorResized.png\">"; //you can walk this part of the map
                }else{
                    map[i][j]="<img class=\"nonWalkble\"// you cannot walk this part of the map src=\"mapTiles/volcanoresize.png\">";
                }    
                ;
            }
            $("#tableGame").append("<tr><td>"+ map[i] + "</td></tr>") // here i print the elements of the array
        }  
    }


mapGenerate();
```